# group by date from date column in yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: sql, date, group-by

I have a table with these columns: order_id, order_status, order_date, order_quantity, sales, discount_value, product_category, product_sub_category

order date is in yyyy - dd - mm format. i want to query so that the result would be in table like this:
(https://i.ibb.co/cFh4h4K/Capture2.png)

i tried the formula below but it instead gives me so many rows based on the year like this (https://i.ibb.co/fDcjpks/Capture2.png).

```
SELECT 
LEFT(order_date, 4) as years, 
SUM(order_quantity*sales)-SUM(order_quantity*discount_value) AS sales, 
SUM(order_quantity) AS number_of_order 
FROM dqlab_sales_store
WHERE order_status = 'order finished' 
GROUP BY order_date,order_quantity,discount_value;
```

any help? thanks

Comment: Please, add a tag of the DBMS you use and provide table definition as `create table` statement. Date has no any format (some specific day is the same at the time line regardless of how you display it). You need to format the date as a string with `to_char`/`cast`/`format` depending on the dbms you use

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by the year, how about try to use this?

group by years

This is because you save yyyy as a years so the column name will be a years not a order_date.
I hope my answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```sql
SELECT 
LEFT(order_date, 4) as years, 
SUM(order_quantity*sales)-SUM(order_quantity*discount_value) AS sales, 
SUM(order_quantity) AS number_of_order 
FROM dqlab_sales_store
WHERE order_status = 'order finished' 
GROUP BY LEFT(order_date, 4);
```

Comment: this one is it, i just realized that i dont need to add everything to the group by clause. thankss